# "float" Object is not callable in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hello fellow programmers I need some help.
Whenever I run this program I get an Error
File"", Line 7, in ""
TypeError:'float' object is not callable
but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.
Here is the code of the program I made

```
print("Project by team A")
print("This calculator calculates the compound interest")
p=float(input("Enter the principal here :"))
r=float(input("Enter the rate percentage here :"))
t=float(input("Enter the time here :"))
rp=r/100
c=p(1+rp/12)
a=math.pow(c,12*t)
print("The Amount is", a)
input("press Enter to exit")
```

If I am doing something wrong please explain it in simple language as I am still a new programmer.
I would be happy if someone corrects my code or provides a better core as it basically finds the compound interest.
I am grateful to anyone who answers.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Use `*` to perform multiplication. Concatenating symbols like `p(...)` and `rp` have different meanings (as a call to a callable and as a single identifier, respectively).

Comment: Oh yes thanks Brian . I confused with real world mathematics. Thank you!!!

Comment: And I forgot to write import math in start but now my program works fine with no errors.